# Unable to Deploy jbpm-designer-standalone

Tags: jboss, jbpm

I am trying to deploy 7.0.x version of jbpm-designer. I have taken the source code from git [(Link for source code)](https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm-designer/tree/7.0.x)

I followed the steps as given below:
1. Extracted the downloaded zip file and built it using mvn clean install.
2. Tried deploying it in Jboss EAP 7.0.0

But during deployment, I am getting the following error:

> 12:04:19,513 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-designer-standalone.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-designer-standalone.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type PropertyValueExtractor with qualifiers @Default
>     at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public org.kie.workbench.common.forms.dynamic.service.shared.adf.DynamicFormModelGenerator(FormBuildingService, PropertyValueExtractor)
>     at org.kie.workbench.common.forms.dynamic.service.shared.adf.DynamicFormModelGenerator.(DynamicFormModelGenerator.java:0)

```
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

12:04:19,518 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "jbpm-designer-standalone.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-designer-standalone.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-designer-standalone.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type PropertyValueExtractor with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public org.kie.workbench.common.forms.dynamic.service.shared.adf.DynamicFormModelGenerator(FormBuildingService, PropertyValueExtractor)
  at org.kie.workbench.common.forms.dynamic.service.shared.adf.DynamicFormModelGenerator.(DynamicFormModelGenerator.java:0)
"}}

Please help.

Comment: which wildfly are you using? wildfly 8 or wildfly 10?

Comment: Hey.... I am using Wildfly 10

Comment: Hey.. I am sorry I don't really know what the answer is. I thought you were using wildfly 8 and trying to execute jbpm 7. Also, it seems to me the logs are saying about form. Perhaps you could double check in that area. I would prefer to use docker of jbpm tough. Lastly, jbpm 7.3.0 was released 2 weeks ago.